# return values of enum but with class inside a array of the class

Tags: java, enums

I got a class Rating, and I need to return an Rating array with all the values of the enum inside, I'm not being able to achieve that

```
public class Rating implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static Rating [] rates;
    private enum Rates{
        Very_Bad,
        Bad,
        Mediocre,
        Good,
        Very_Good,  
        Excellent;      
    }

    public static Rating[] values() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        rates = new Rating[Rates.values().length];
        rates[0] = Rates.Very_Bad;    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rating.Rates to Rating
        rates[1] = Rates.Bad;         //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rating.Rates to Rating
        rates[2] = Rates.Mediocre;    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rating.Rates to Rating
        rates[3] = Rates.Good;        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rating.Rates to Rating
        rates[4] = Rates.Excellent;   //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rating.Rates to Rating
        rates[5] = Rates.Excellent;   //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rating.Rates to Rating
        return rates;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have written `Rating[]` instead of `Rates[]`. Your enums are object of `Rates`, but you are treating them as objects of `Rating`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. There's no relationship between `Rating` and `Rates`. You can't put the latter into an array of the former. If you want to return an array of all `Rates`, just `return Rates.values()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any other way for this to make sense than `Rating` being the enum:

```
public enum Rating {
    VERY_BAD,
    BAD,
    MEDIOCRE,
    GOOD,
    VERY_GOOD,  
    EXCELLENT;      
}
```

As members of enums are a type of constants, they are usually expressed in all caps.

This way, the code from your professor makes sense:

```
protected static final Rating RATING = Rating.values()[Rating.values().length-1];
```

Which then will be the last value in the enum. (The `values`-method is native to enums, no need to create it.)

Edit:

```
//Representation of the act of rating something
public class Rating {
    private Rate rate;
    private ThingToRate thing;

    //getters/setters/stuff

}

//Possible choices for rating something
public enum Rate {
    VERY_BAD,
    BAD,
    MEDIOCRE,
    GOOD,
    VERY_GOOD,  
    EXCELLENT;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem like the correct way to use an enum. I'll add an alternative approach that makes sense..

Comment: the problem was me now xD... it wasn't the professor code it was mine, it was my constructor calling the constructor... Thanks for the help my friend :D

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this approach:

```
private enum Rates {
    Very_Bad(0), 
    Bad(1), 
    Mediocre(2), 
    Good(3), 
    Very_Good(4), 
    Excellent(5);

    private final int value;

    Rates(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Rates fromValue(int value) {
        for (Rates rates : Rates.values()) {
            if(Objects.equals(rates.getValue(), value)) {
                return rates;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value: " + value);
    }
}
```

This would allow a mapping between values to enum keys.

```
...
Rates rate = Rates.fromValue(x);
...
```

This also works with other `value` types.

Or maybe you take it a bit further and use the factory design pattern to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is that I need to return an array of Rating that has the values of Rates...

Comment: What is the point of this? Using an enum is way better than using integers that are then mapped to an enum.

Comment: yeah but the professor already has the tests (JUnit) and we need to do the code for all the methods and classes

Comment: @Tobb Using a value in conjunction with an enum key allows you to group constant values together, making things more readable. You can than use the Enum to allow method calls, where you do not have to perform range checks (for the in value) because you get a enum key instead.

Comment: I don't see how grouping integers is any easier than grouping actual enum values. `Rates.Good` has meaning, `3` could be anything (`setRate(Rates.Good)` vs `setRate(3)`). Only place I've seen such a construct is when you have some external representation that needs to be mapped to an enum, and even then it's a pain to work with. Using it for no appearant reason is just pointless.

Comment: `setRate(-1)`  and `setRate(123456789)` are possible exposing an int, or String.